# Destroy Method in Ruby Application does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, web-applications, blogs, destroy

For my ruby on rails application the destroy method doesn't work.

This is how the **controller.rb** looks like:

```
def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy!
    redirect_to '/posts/new(.:format)'
end
```

The show.html.erb:

```
<div class="btn">
    <%= link_to "Delete", :method => :delete %>
</div>
```

And the  **application.js**:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

When the post url is http://localhost:3000/posts/bestpostever
and I click the delete button, I get directed to http://localhost:3000/posts/bestpostever?method=delete but that's it. The post still gets shown.

Comment: show the rails server log that prints when you click on the "delete" button.

Comment: Ok, you need to put the the path in the `link_to`, like `<%= link_to "Delete",  @post, :method => :delete %>` . `@post` is just the post object, you are using to display the post details in the show.html.erb. The variable names may be different in your case, so use what you have in the show page instead of `@post`. Idea is it has to be the object, you want to delete.

Comment: That worked. Problem solved, thanks!

Comment: But I got another problem. Since I added the lines of code into the application.js my dropdown menu (which uses js does not work anymore). Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: You have to write all your JS inside the `$(document).on('ready page:load', function(event) {
  // apply non-idempotent transformations to the body
});` method always. Look [examples](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-classic#events)